# Who can undownvote besides me?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

I downvoted a post yesterday and it got undownvoted today. Can the privileged users access my account and make these changes? Who else can make this change?

Comment: Did you cast multiple downvotes upon posts of the same user?

Comment: Are you referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630824/nhibernate-large-data-retrieval-in-single-query/11631046#11631046)?

Comment: @animuson, exactly! I guess this is the reason why I am getting my points back.

Comment: @deco, no I downvoted someone on meta. Today my reputation activity shows that he got undownvoted and I got the points back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jason as far as I know, you can upvote and downvote on any post and it shall not rollback,  unless you have a serial upvote or downvote on a particular account.  Technically, anyone with access to the database (which would be the SE developers) could change the vote, however this is only done when the voting is found to violate the rules (serial voting and using a sockpuppet to vote for your own posts).

Another thing might be that your vote was not reversed, but that someone else upvoted that post .

Comment: That is exactly what happened. I downvoted the same user on several questions. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Remember, voting is intended to occur on posts, the content, not on the people, and there are safeguards in place to prevent this from being abused.

Comment: @jmort253, so it is confirmed that it **can** be moderated. Now this answer supports the confirmation, while the other answer below this one (by PresleyDias) is contradicting the statement (considering privileged user is moderator). He said "Surely **Not**". Interestingly both answers are getting upvotes. Wouldn't it cause confusion to the future readers? Are people upvoting the wrong answer because it has screenshots?

Comment: @JasonWilliams look there must be some moderator tools for that see my reputation on SO there are - 840 points which was due to reversal of serial upvote from some other accounts http://stackoverflow.com/users/766108/avi-kumar-manku?tab=reputation

Comment: @Jason, I feel the different answers were only caused by your, ahum, not very specific question.

Comment: @JasonWilliams: Moderators can not *see* what votes you made, but there are automated systems in place that *can*. So no human sees this, but automated heuristics detect serial up and downvoting and undo those when thresholds are crossed. Moderators can undo votes by hand too, but they do so blind (they use other evidence like comments).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Moderators can't reverse anyone's votes. We (employees) can, but we don't make a habit of it and it's not exactly an easy button beside every post.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ah, noted; important distinction.

Answer (score 3):

> I downvoted a post yesterday and it got undownvoted today.

If you have downvoted a post then it will appear like this

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFgRV.jpg]

was the color still orange when you check the post again?

Or is the post like this now?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6EcW.jpg]

If it's not orange then **you** probably has double clicked on it (undownvoted it) like 
[animuson' comment says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141302/who-can-undownvote-besides-me#comment399845_141302).

> Can the privileged users access my account and make these changes?

Surely **Not**.

Comment: Actually I didn't double clicked the vote. Yesterday it was orange. Today the orange arrow is gone. According to `animuson` and `Avi Kumar Manku`, this is due to the reason I downvoted the same user more than once on different places.